# Group all files in import statements and export statement in ES6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-modules

I have these three files - `tabs`, `routes`, `urls` in a folder called `config`

**Folder structure**

```
config
| - urls 
| - tabs
| - routes
```

Here's what I tried so far. Created an `index.js` file in `config` folder where I could write all the export statements.

```
export * from './routes'
export * from './urls'
export * from './tabs'
```

I want to nest all the files like below in `import` statement and use them wherever needed in other `.js` files

```
import {tabs, routes, urls } from '../config'
```

How do I group all the files in one single import statement. Could anyone please help?

Comment: What do you mean by "How do I chain the files in one single import statement.?"?

Comment: I meant writing an import statement like this `import {tabs, routes, urls } from '../config'` Meaning, using a single import statement and group all files that are in that folder.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?

config/index.js

```
export * as routes from './routes'
export * as urls from './urls'
export * as tabs from './tabs'
```

Answer (score 0):

Use import *

`import * from '../config/';`

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do it this way. But, is there a better way?

```
import routes from './routes';
import urls from './urls';
import tabs from './tabs';

export { routes, tabs, urls };
```

And, I'm calling it like this

```
import {tabs, routes, urls } from '../config'
```